# How to input unique item into a listview

Tags: c#, listview

I want to build a small application in C#. Where user will input in textbox and after click a button the information will display in a listview. My listview has 3 column header. I want to input unique words in listview and if the information is already exist then a messagebox will display the error. Everything was almost completed but I got an exception. Don't understand what I missed?

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
int serial = 1;
private void saveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string code = codeTextBox.Text;
    string name = nameTextBox.Text;

    foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subItem in item.SubItems)
    {
        if (subItem.Text == code)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Code or Department name already exist");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Text = (serial.ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(code);
            item.SubItems.Add(name);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
        serial++;
    }
}
```

Here is the exception details----

> "Cannot add or insert the item '2' in more than one place. You must
>   first remove it from its current location or clone it.\r\nParameter
>   name: item"

Comment: `but I got an exception` Will you post the exception details or do you leave it to our imaginations.

Comment: Here is the exception details------"Cannot add or insert the item '2' in more than one place. You must first remove it from its current location or clone it.\r\nParameter name: item"

Comment: @YousufYamin you need to create a new `ListViewItem` for the list. Your code is reusing the one initially created.

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.LINQ` for do this. Is much better:

```
if (item.SubItems.Any(t => t.Text == code))
    MessageBox.Show("Code or Department name already exist");
else
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.Text = serial.ToString();
    item.SubItems.Add(code);
    item.SubItems.Add(name);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

You also need to create a new `ListViewItem` for each new item added to the list. The original code was reusing the same item which cannot be added twice once already added to a parent.